# Clean way to circumvent name mangling for a module?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using Python's ctypes to interface a C library file, running [ctypesgen](http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/) to create a wrapper module (e.g, api.py)  which I can import. It happens that many of the C functions and macros have names starting with double underscores, which are treated as "private" by Python and invoke name mangling when used in a class definition.

For instance, this works:

```
import api
api.__someGetter()
```

But this doesn't

```
import api
class MyClass(object):
    i = api.__someGetter()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_MyClass__someGetter'
```

This *does* work:

```
i = api.__dict__['__someGetter']()
```

But it doesn't seem very elegant or easily readable to me - the code will be littered with calls to dictionary keys.

Is there a better way to disable or work around name mangling for a module?

(The fact that it's a C library probably isn't relevant to the answer, but hopefully it explains why I can't just change the naming convention.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For curiosity's sake, here is a way to achieve this effect. It wraps the module in a class which has [custom attribute access methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) that just discard the first part of the mangled name.  It's certainly a bit of a hack, and may not work in all cases -- I'm not recommending it for serious use!

```
    class Wrapper(object):
        def __init__(self, module):
            for name in module.__dict__:
                self.__dict__[name] = module.__dict__[name]

        #__getattr__ is called only if regular access failed
        def __getattr__(self, name): 
            try:
                return self.__dict__['__'+name.split('__', 1)[1]]
            except (IndexError, KeyError):
                raise AttributeError, name

        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            try:
                self.__dict__['__'+name.split('__', 1)[1]] = value
            except IndexError:   #no double underscores to split
                self.__dict__[name] = value
```

Usage:

```
import cwrapper 
api = Wrapper(cwrapper)

class MyClass(object):
    i = api.__some_Getter() #works
```

Answer (score 2):

You can re-export names in Python, converting the double underscore to a single underscore.

```
import api
for name in api.__dict__:
    if name.startswith('__'):
        globals()[name[1:]] = api.__dict__[name]
```

This will change all of the double underscores in `api` to single underscores in the current module.  This module can then be imported from another.

**Note:** It is **incorrect** to name functions in C that begin with two underscores.  See section 7.1.3 "Reserved Identifiers" of n1526.  Using names that begin with double underscores in C is "undefined behavior", which is the technical term for "don't do it."

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thanks for your answer. Ideally, though, I would like to keep the names consistent with the library.

Comment: @Lack: That's simply impossible in Python.  You cannot just make up new names that begin with a double underscore.

Comment: Alright, I will have to deal with that. Good point about the standard, as well. I'm not in control of the library but I should mention the identifiers in question have an additional prefix (omitted in my example) identifying them as being for testing only, so I'm not worried.