# Is there a way to bypass dunder magic in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-appsync

I have some AWS lambdas written in python where I return python data classes, which are marshalled to dictionaries then returned to be translated into graphql by appsync. The graphql schema as defined (not by me) is a little bit polymorphic - For example, in one case the object I intend to return is a `UserProfile`, and the graphql schema defines the following:

```
union ProfileContext = UserProfile | PublicUserProfile
```

(There are also nested instances of this) In order to return this, appsync requires that the dictionary I pass back to it describing a `ProfileContext` has a `__typename` attribute. My first instinct was the following:

```
@dataclass
class UserProfile:

    ...

    @property
    def __typename(self):
        return 'UserProfiles'
```

But of course I fell foul of python's dunder magic, and the property actually gets the name `_UserProfile__typename`. Is there a way to give the python object a property that is actually named `__typename`? (Basically bypassing the dunder magic in order to make appsync happy)

If not I will be reduced to having to manually traverse object trees after unmarshalling, or create some sort of custom unmarshaller using something like marshmallow.

Comment: If I understood correctly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11697957/2011147) should help. Check it out.

Comment: That is the correct answer. Thank you!